# Is combustion considered a redox reaction?

Tags: redox, combustion

When carbon combusts with oxygen, is this considered a redox reaction since the oxygen atoms gain electrons and the carbon atoms lose them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, yes.  If the reaction involves oxygen going from the oxidation state of zero in $\ce{O_2}$ to an oxidation state of -2, then there is oxidation and the reaction is a redox reaction.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? When you say "in general", does that mean that there are some special cases? If so, you may want to add them to your answer, it'll make it more interesting...

Comment: @ManishEarth There's nothing 'in general' about it.  a combustion reaction requires an oxidizer; therefore it is always a redox reaction.  (Late comment, I know.)